# Updating cells in a DataGrid when other cells are changed

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

When I change the value of any cell in a row, I want to dynamically change other cells in the same row. For example, in the following grid, when I change 1 to 3 in the second row, the value of 5 must change to 3. *(The edit button only saves changes into the database.)*

[image]

Here's the xaml code of my `DataGrid`. I have tried using `SelectedCellsChanged` and `SelectionChanged` events but I wasn't successful.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" x:Uid="MyDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    Height="226" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,111,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="684" ColumnWidth="*"
    AlternationCount="2" SelectionMode="Single"
    SelectedCellsChanged="MyDataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged"
    SelectionChanged="MyDataGrid_SelectionChanged" >

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ProductName}" Header="Ürün Adı" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=StoreName}" Header="Şube Adı" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Day1}" Header="Pazartesi" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Day2}" Header="Salı" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Day3}" Header="Çarşamba" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Day4}" Header="Perşembe" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Day5}" Header="Cuma" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Day6}" Header="Cumartesi" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Day7}" Header="Pazar" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit Row">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="Edit" Click="EditButton_Click" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 7):

You have taken the wrong approach - do not try and rely on manipulating things in response to a user interface event like `SelectedCellsChanged`.

Instead you can manipulate and update the related properties in the setter of the bound properties on the bound data object. If you then fire a property change notification for the affected properties (which they should be doing themselves in their own setters) then the values in the `DataGrid` will be automatically updated via the binding.

**Example:**

this is contrived but it should show you what I mean. If your data object that each row of the grid binds to contains a bunch of properties with [private backing members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132377/why-use-private-members-then-use-public-properties-to-set-them), and the data object implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) then you can do something like this:

```
public class MyDataClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Day1
    {
        get { return _day1; }
        set 
        {
            _day1 = value;
            UpdateProperties();
        }
    }

    public int Day2
    {
        get { return _day2; }
        set 
        {
            _day2 = value;
            UpdateProperties();
        }
    }

    // etc, repeat for the next three 'Day' properties

    private void UpdateProperties()
    {
        //adjust the private backing members for each property:
        _day1 = someValue;
        _day2 = someOtherValue;

        OnPropertyChanged("Day1");
        OnPropertyChanged("Day2");
        //etc, notify for each property that you adjusted
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangeEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int _day1, _day2, //etc... ;
}
```

Of course when you do this you want to be very careful about setting properties - you don't want to get into a circular calling situation which will cause a stack overflow. After you have adjusted the private backing member and then fired the `PropertyChanged` event for each updated property the row in the grid should be updated automatically via the binding.

Comment: how can i do this ? sorry, i am beginner in wpf. can you give any example ?

Comment: This lead me in the right direction, thanks. Usually, i let my ViewModels handle all the NotifyPropertyChanged-events, but in this special case, it's ok to soften up the pattern a little bit and let the DataModels of the records in the DataGrid handle their synchronization by themself.

Answer (score 0):

handler(this, new PropertyChangeEventArgs(propertyName));
not
handler(this, new PropertyChangeEventArgs(propertyName));